# Why an error "blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-4" despite using Mono.fromCallable()?

Tags: kotlin, azure-blob-storage, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I agree that reactive code should not block, but...

In the following method, findTenantStorageFactory(), I need to block on the tenantId, so the method can return a specific Factory for a tenant.  I found instructions from Project Reactor that I need to wrap the method in a Mono.fromCallable() and use the boundedElastic() scheduler.  However, when I run this code in the debugger, I receive the dreaded: "block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported" error. I've tried a million ideas, but cannot make any progress.  I'd appreciate your suggestions.

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
fun findTenantStorageFactory(tenantId: Mono<TenantId>):
  Mono<Either<BaseAzureBlobStorageException, MultitenantAzureBlobStorageFactory>> {
    val myValue: Callable<Either<
                   BaseAzureBlobStorageException, 
                   MultitenantAzureBlobStorageFactory>> =

    Callable { lookupTenantBlobStorageFactory(tenantId.block()!!, factories) }

    return Mono.fromCallable<Either<
                  BaseAzureBlobStorageException, 
                  MultitenantAzureBlobStorageFactory>>(myValue)
               .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
    }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private val blobStorageClientBuilder: AzureBlobClientBuilder
 get() = 
   findTenantStorageFactory(tenantId).block()!!
     .fold({ throw it }, { it.blobStorageClient })!!
```

```
/////////////////////////////// ERROR ///////////////////////////////////
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-4
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.4.0-M1.jar:3.4.0-M1]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
```

Comment: If your whole application is reactive then, there is definitely a way to avoid "blocking" calls. If you can share little bit more code, like how is this "findTenantStorageFactory" method being used and all, I will surely try to help you out. However if your application is non-reactive then you can use BlobServiceClient instead of BlobServiceAsyncClient from azure blob storage sdk v12

Comment: What is breaking reactivity is that we are using the Azure Blob Storage SDK for Java v12, and it has block() statements, so there is not much that we can do about their code.  I could write a generator to wrap around it, but it seems that Project Reactor recommended what I've done as a solution.  I need to resolve this issue very soon, so I may switch to directly using their rest API, but I don't know if that may just present a new issue...

Comment: isn't one of these `block()` statements made eagerly when you instantiate the mono ? the `Suppressed` error should point to the code that calls block, which you seem to have edited out.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that you need to block on `tenantId`? I would use `map` to convert a Mono to a Mono. If `lookupTenantBlobStorageFactory` is a long-running method and you want to avoid blocking the current thread, `publishOn` should help you. Something like this:

```
fun findTenantStorageFactory(tenantId: Mono<TenantId>):
  Mono<Either<BaseAzureBlobStorageException, MultitenantAzureBlobStorageFactory>> {
     return tenantId.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .map({ id -> lookupTenantBlobStorageFactory(id, factories) })
}
```